# Spring boot serving static content with Post call

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, http

I need to load my react app by serving my index.html file by spring boot when I get a post http call. Currently I get : "Method Not Allowed, Request method 'POST' not supported"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ResourceHttpRequestHandler used by Spring to service static content does support only GET and HEAD methods. You need this way to add POST method :

```
    @Bean
public ResourceHttpRequestHandler resourceHttpRequestHandler() {
    ResourceHttpRequestHandler requestHandler = new ResourceHttpRequestHandler();
    requestHandler.setLocationValues(Arrays.asList("file:D:/UAM/frontend3/build/")); // could ne classpath path
    requestHandler.setSupportedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name());
    return requestHandler;
}

@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping sampleServletMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
    Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
    urlProperties.put("/**", "resourceHttpRequestHandler");
    mapping.setMappings(urlProperties);
    return mapping;
}
```